# Sign of matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

Given two real values matrices `A` and `B` with size `m x n` and `n x l`, I'm interested in the sign of the elements in their matrix multiplication, i.e.,:

```
C = sign(A x B)
```

Given the fact that both `A` and `B` are very large matrices and I'm only interested in the sign of the output elements, is there a way to approximate `C` rather than computing this computationally expensive matrix multiplication?

I'm looking for an approximation and a certain degree of error would be totally acceptable.

PS: One common scenario is when the elements of `A` and `B` are -1 or 1